# Why does my IF statement doesn't catch the date in-between

Tags: php, if-statement, date-range

I have many records in my database with different dates but my code doesn't catch the dates and it doesn't show up. What's the problem?

**Here is my code**

```
$year = date("Y");
$sem1_s = date("M-d-Y", strtotime(date('Y') . '-8-1 00:00:00'));
$sem1_e = date("M-d-Y", strtotime(date('Y') . '-12-31 00:00:00'));

$sem2_s = date("M-d-Y", strtotime(date('Y') . '-01-1 00:00:00'));
$sem2_e = date("M-d-Y", strtotime(date('Y') . '-06-30 00:00:00'));
$date = '2015-10-15';

$date2 = date("M-d-Y", strtotime(date('Y') . '-3-1 00:00:00'));

if($date2 >= $sem1_s && $date2 <= $sem1_e){
    echo $date2;
    echo "First Sem";
}
else if($date2 >= $sem2_s && $date2 <= $sem2_e){
    echo $date2;
    echo "Second Sem";
}
else{
    echo "error";
}
```

Comment: Try date_diff function for counting the difference between two dates http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-diff.php

Comment: your date objects are fine, problem is with your `if` statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in your `if` statement as I mentioned earlier in the comment below your question, problem is with your `if` statement. so change that to this:

```
if (strtotime($date2) >= strtotime($sem1_s) && strtotime($date2) <= strtotime($sem1_e))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your if statement like this

```
$year = date("Y");
$sem1_s = date("M-d-Y", strtotime(date('Y') . '-8-1 00:00:00'));
$sem1_e = date("M-d-Y", strtotime(date('Y') . '-12-31 00:00:00'));

$sem2_s = date("M-d-Y", strtotime(date('Y') . '-01-1 00:00:00'));
$sem2_e = date("M-d-Y", strtotime(date('Y') . '-06-30 00:00:00'));
$date = '2015-10-15';

$date2 = date("M-d-Y", strtotime(date('Y') . '-3-1 00:00:00'));

if($date2 >= $sem1_s || $date2 <= $sem1_e){
    echo $date2;
    echo "First Sem";
}
else if($date2 >= $sem2_s || $date2 <= $sem2_e){
   echo $date2;
   echo "Second Sem";
}
else{
    echo "error";


}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you cannot use greater than or less than sign in a string
you should convert your variables as a strtotime.

```
    if(strtotime($date2) >= strtotime($sem1_s) && strtotime($date2) <= strtotime($sem1_e)){
    echo $date2;
    echo "First Sem";
    }
    else if(strtotime($date2) >= strtotime($sem2_s) && strtotime($date2) <= strtotime($sem2_e)){
     echo $date2;
    echo "Second Sem";
    }
    else{
    echo "error";
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you need to convert dates to [UNIX timestamp](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) for comparison.

The below will return the desired result,

```
if(strtotime($date2) >= strtotime($sem1_s) && strtotime($date2) <= strtotime($sem1_e)){
   echo $date2;
   echo "First Sem";
}
else if(strtotime($date2) >= strtotime($sem2_s) && strtotime($date2) <= strtotime($sem2_e)){
   echo $date2;
   echo "Second Sem";
}
else{
   echo "error";
}
```